# Can someone help me understand this program?

Tags: c, recursion

This is my program in `C`.

```
f(int n){
    if(!n){
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%d", f(--n));
    printf("*");
    return (n+1);
}

int main()
{
    f(3);
    return 0;
}
```

and it prints:

> 0*1*2*

now i cant see why it gets inside first `printf` and gets down for one in (--n)
but does not print anything until it reaches 0

Comment: This is not a good example for recursion but would be a good (simple enough) for understanding recursion.

Comment: Why are you writing C using a 30+ years obsolete style? Who taught you to do this?

Comment: My professor give us this to understand the process of recursion

Comment: @MarkoPrtenjača I think they should focus on teaching you how to program C in the year 2018, instead of how to do so in the year 1978. But that's my personal opinion...

Comment: @Lundin yeah i know they have really wierd way sometimes when showing us these type of programs haha

Answer (score 8):

**A picture is worth a thousand words.**

- solid arrows = function calls
- dotted arrows = function returns.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't print anything until it reaches 0 as in `printf` the `f(--n)` is executed first to calculate the result. This causes the function to recursively go on until it reaches 0. Then it returns the values one level up and starts printing your result `0*1*2`.

Answer (score 1):

With this program you will have the following flow:

```
f(3) -> call f(2)
f(2) -> call f(1)
f(1) -> call f(0)
f(0) -> return 0

f(1) -> print(0) print(*) and return 0+1
f(2) -> print(1) print(*) and return 1+1
f(3) -> print(2) print(*) and return 2+1

main
```

Which will print 0*1*2*